# Is it possible to find out what started a program?

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting

Is it possible to determine what (program) started a certain program (or a service)? I.e., how can I find the source of what's opening up certain programs on my Windows 7 machine?

This isn't so much a question about a certain problematic program. Rather, It would be extremely useful in troubleshooting to have a utility that could determine this.

Comment: if the parent process is not died, you can use [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to show the process tree to find out it's parent process

Comment: @LiuYan刘研: just to note, you posted that while I was composing my answer, and getting a screenshot. If you had *posted* that as an answer, I'd have simply have edited in the screenshot into your answer.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, never mind about that, i'm not going to steal your answer just because of my comment happened before your answer, it's your answer :)

Comment: On the contrary, Had you posted, I wouldn't have, entirely honourably and accidentally stolen your answer. It would have popped up there was a new answer, I'd have checked and you would have gotten it. You obviously know what tool to use ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process explorer should allow you to do that - processes are organised in a tree structure, and you can click on them to tell what's being accessed by various processes

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Crack open the command prompt and use **Netstat** with the **-b** switch. No need to download programs that junk your computer up when you have native tools at your disposal.

Comment: er, netstat only tells you network connections, not processes and what spawned them